# Reusing Activity and buttons for Quiz Application in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-button

I am making a small quiz application as part of a bigger application. I have about 18 questions and I don't want to make a new activity for each question. How do I change the button implementation everytime a button is clicked. Say for Question 1 I give answer A, the question and buttons should change for Question 2.

Thanks,

Comment: Show us what you have done to accomplish this

Comment: @Varun you can also use the view pager for that if you don't want to open another activity

Comment: you can create one common method to display questions, keep track of current question no and on button click load next question

Answer (score 0):

set an int on Shared Preference for the question no to be asked

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("QUIZ", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("question_no",1);
editor.apply();
```

Then on button click

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int q_no = preferences.getInt("question_no",1);
        switch (q_no){
            case 1:
                textView.setText("Question 1:");
                break;
            case 2:
                textView.setText("Question 2:");
                break;
            case 3:
                textView.setText("Question 3:");
                break;
            ...
            default:
                /*End all question*/
        }

        editor.putInt("question_no",q_no+1);
        editor.apply();
    }
});
```

Comment: this would work for just one instance right? I want it to work for all 18 questions. I'm thinking of using switch statement and a count variable

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks!

Comment: Hey! this solved my problem! Thanks. Although, when I move to the next question, my radio button remains checked at the previous answer. I tried using setChecked(false) but then I can't select the option